# Which one will run faster

Tags: python, performance

lst is a very large list of integers

a,b and c are numbers

- code 1

```
    if a in lst or b in lst or c in lst:
        print("found in lst")
```

- code 2

```
    if a in lst:
        print("found in lst")

    elif b in lst:
        print("found in lst")

    elif c in lst:
        print("found in lst")
```

is there any speed difference in code 1 and code 2

Comment: What happened when you measured the performance for them?

Comment: `{a, b, c} & set(lst)` would be faster

Comment: @hansolo It depends, on the data, actually. If `a` is the first element of `lst`, the original code (either of them) is the fastest possible.

Comment: Sure. It depends on the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, both of your code samples will run equally since the `or` operator supports short-cuiting. That means that Python will *not* evaluate subsequent conditions unless the one before it evaluated to `False`. For example, if we have `A or B or C`, unless both `A` and `B` are `False`, Python will *not* evaluate `C`.

The same thing occurs with your `if` statements: `C` will only be evaluated if both `A` and `B` are `False`.

However, on large lists, you shouldn't be doing any sort of query like this. If don't need to index the elements of the list, a hash  table (Dictionary) is almost always better since you'll get O(1) lookup time.